# High CPU usage on first load of angular application

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-template

There is angular 2 application with webpack bundling.
I've built app with webpack, there are vendor.bundle and main.bundle scripts.
When I am trying to open app in browser I'm getting high CPU usage after vendor.budle loads.

I've started CPU profiler in Chrome and see that there are two places:

1. template compiling
2. template normalization

[image]

How to prevent hard template compiling and what core issue of this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AOT compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) is what you're looking for. Without it, your browser has to compile all templates on the fly, which is causing said high CPU load.

Comment: You was right! Thank you. What about development configuration? Is any practice of using AOT in dev webpack config?

Comment: I wouldn't use AOT during development. Generally you'll want to be able to make changes quickly and have them appear instantly, rather than having to wait for the slow AOT compiler to finish doing its thing. So just use JIT during development and when you're done, run AOT and minify for production.